# Php get variable and store to file, throws error

Tags: php, string, variables

So I have this code,

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$var_str = $_GET['t0'];
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('temps.php', $var);
include 'temps.php';
echo $text;
?>
```

And i want it to store the variable that it gets from  http://Mylink.com/apage.php?t0=3
(or basically that 3) to temps.php? when i go to that page, it gives the following error.

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function 3() in **/home/content/f/e/d/apage.php** on line **3**

Comment: `$_GET['t0']` is already the input variable. `($text, true)` does not belong there. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @mario Sorry i was mixing various code together, as you can tell im not very good at php.

Comment: @mario I changed the code to what it is above, and it now reads: <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in <b>/home/content/f/e/d/temps.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />

Comment: Ignore the comment above, i can no longer edit it...  @mario I changed the code to what it is above, and it now reads: <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in <b>/home/content/f/e/d/temps.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> When visiting mysite.com/apage.php?t0=3

Comment: I believe you are getting a new error and notice now. Writing user input into PHP files is not an advisable approach generally. But what are you planning to do here? Is `temps.php` a template file? Are you trying to create one .php script per page? Because just writing variables to one file and including it right back seems a bit longwinded by itself.

Comment: The echoing back is to make sure it works, I am having an arduino post the variable using that method, and need the php to store it in a file.

Comment: By the way, temps was supposed to be temp but I misspelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will save only the value of $_GET['t0']:

```
$content = $_GET['t0'].PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('temps.php', $var);
```

The rest looks really insecure and i don't see the point. 
Could you paste the wanted end result of temps.php?

**EDIT**
ok in that case use this to save the content to a txt file:

**somefile.php**

```
 $content = $_GET['t0'];
 file_put_contents('temps.txt', $content);
```

Put this in temps.php:

**temps.php**

```
$text = file_get_contents('temps.txt');
```

and echo $text; will work

Comment: I want to be able to do echo $text; from any php page(with temps.php included into it) and have it show t0=(the variable)

Comment: put this i temps.php? i assumed that meant to put the following line in temps.php

Comment: so somefile.php is                                                 
 $content = $_GET['t0'].PHP_EOL;
 file_put_contents('temps.txt', $var); and to get that i do $text = file_get_contents('temps.txt');
echo $var

Comment: i cleaned up the code a bit, but yes, you got the idea. Its nice and easy :)

Comment: Thanks again! now ill need to be asking another question related to the device that puts the variable :P.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this to prepare some output for writing to a .php include:

```
 $var = "<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
```

While the approach is okay, you overlooked some syntax gotchas here.

First you wrote `\$$text`. This will result in a literal `$` being kept in your $var output variable. But `$text` will be gone because it is interpolated into an empty string in your $var string.

$text was an undefined variable at this point in your code. Raise [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/error_reporting) to [`E_ALL`](http://php.net/E_ALL) to notice such issues.

So in the end, this would become your output `temps.php` file:

```
<?php  $ = 3; ?>
```

To get a proper variable name there, thus better use:

```
$var = "<?php  \$text = $var_str;   ?>"; 
#                ^
```

(Just one escaped dollar sign here, no double $$.)

To make your code somewhat more safe to deploy, you should also escape or sanitize `$var_str` before (it was potentially user input). Use [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) or [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) here:

```
$var_str = $_GET['t0'];
$var_str = var_export($var_str, 1);
$var = "<?php   \$text = $var_str;    ?>";
```

Then your output file becomes:

```
<?php  $text = 3; ?>
```

But would also work for strings.